How to treat ' (single-quote) as an ordinary character in HTML mode?
In a mode derived from html-mode, I want to remove the property that ' opens a quote. I found character properties in the manual, but the following in the .emacs init file does not work:
(define-derived-mode dox-mode
  html-mode "dox"
  "Major mode for Doxygen.")

(defun my-dox-mode-hook ()
  (put-char-code-property ?\' 'bracket-type nil))

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.dox\\'" . dox-mode))
(add-hook 'dox-mode-hook 'my-dox-mode-hook)

I found this question, but it does not have a solution: Disable syntax highlighting after single quote in HTML mode

You should not mess with the char-code properties. These are standard properties determined by Unicode. The syntax-table is what you are looking for. This only as a comment, because sgml-mode/html-mode seems to be a non-trivial case.

In sgml-mode which is the base for html-mode they are messing around with syntax tables quite a lot. For an instance there is a special syntax table sgml-tag-syntax-table for tags.

Thank you for looking into this and going down that rabbit hole.
